# Remove white background from image with opencv python

Tags: python, python-3.x, image-processing, opencv

I have been trying to remove background from a logo and use it as a watermark on product images.I tried to remove background from logo with masking but it also removing black fonts from logo. i need help in removing background without changing the logo. images are attached below. output image is the image i get as output with this code.
logo image: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yMG6cDuPt8q3EqOJ4Amzp_czWq5hrGS5/view?usp=sharing
product image: https://drive.google.com/file/d/13SmkTgBtWD3yIJq-qGI0aZJ-hjaLbyuB/view?usp=sharing
output image: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1k-fQ9tPUEJKQXPdmdB2ajtliAAG4irNs/view?usp=sharing

this is my code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread('images/1L2Z3A443AAMC.jpg')
logo = cv2.imread('water2.png')
logo = cv2.resize(logo,(int(img.shape[0]/1.2),int(img.shape[1]/2)))
logo_gray = cv2.cvtColor(logo,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret,mask= cv2.threshold(logo_gray,245,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
mask_inv = cv2.bitwise_not(mask)
logo_final = cv2.bitwise_and(logo,logo, mask=mask_inv)


h_img,w_img,_ = img.shape
h_logo,w_logo,_ = logo.shape
center_y = int(h_img/2)
center_x = int(w_img/2)
top_y = center_y - (int(h_logo/2)) 
left_x = center_x - (int(w_logo/2)) 
bottom_y = top_y + h_logo
right_x = left_x + w_logo

roi = img[top_y:bottom_y,left_x:right_x]
result = cv2.addWeighted(roi,1,logo_final,1,0)
img[top_y:bottom_y,left_x:right_x] = result
cv2.imwrite('sample.jpg',img)
```

Comment: What is the question? Please [edit] your post to make it explicit what you are asking.

Comment: @CrisLuengo  okay

Comment: When you put black text from the logo onto near black in the background image, the black text will not show. What do you expect it to do?

Comment: @fmw42 this logo is provided by client.

Comment: Make the logo smaller and place it in one of the corners in the white area.

Comment: @fmw42 client want the logo in the middle of the image.

Comment: The only way I can think to help would be to increase the brightness of the background image. If the logo has black and the image has black, the black in the logo won't be readable. The alternative is for your client to change his logo

Comment: @fmw42 you are right, i tried multiple ways and failed. I asked my client to change to logo lets see.

Answer (score 0):

In order to remove the background from a logo. We need to used masking. A masking for the foreground and another masking for the background.

```
logo = cv2.imread("water2.png", -1)
logo_mask = logo[:,:,3]
logo_mask_inv = cv2.bitwise_not(logo_mask)
logo = logo[:,:,0:3]

logo_background = cv2.bitwise_and(roi, roi, mask=logo_mask_inv)
logo_foreground = cv2.bitwise_and(logo, logo, mask=logo_mask)
final_logo = cv2.add(logo_background, logo_foreground)
```

Comment: This code works same as my code. Got the same results